# Python error while building payload.bin with ninja

Tags: python, linux, ninja, android-soong

So I'm trying to build Project Fluid for my Poco F3 (alioth) and I'm having this problem at the second last target of the build (creating a payload.bin for the OTA package):

> ERROR:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/krakeen06/fluid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_t
> arget_files.py", line 2322, in 
> File "/home/krakeen06/fluid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_t
> arget_files.py", line 2295, in main
> File "/home/krakeen06/fluid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_t
> arget_files.py", line 1936, in GenerateAbOtaPackage
> File "/home/krakeen06/fluid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_t
> arget_files.py", line 407, in Generate
> File "/home/krakeen06/fluid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_t
> arget_files.py", line 381, in _Run
> File "/home/krakeen06/fluid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/common.py"
> , line 281, in RunAndCheckOutput
> args, proc.returncode, output))
> ExternalError: Failed to run command '['brillo_update_payload', 'generate', '--payloa
> d', '/home/krakeen06/fluid/out/soong/.temp/payload-HqmpdX.bin', '--target_image', '/h
> ome/krakeen06/fluid/out/target/product/alioth/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediate
> s/fluid_alioth-target_files-eng.krakeen06.zip', '--max_timestamp', '1625570460']' (ex
> it code 134):
> 11:36:28 ninja failed with: exit status 1

I tried updating my python packages. Can't seem to find a solution. Maybe anybody here can help me? Thanks in advance.

My machine is running on an Azure server. It's Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with 6 cores and 56 GB of RAM.

PS: Device and vendor trees from here: https://github.com/AliothDevelopment

ROM source: https://github.com/Project-Fluid

Comment: The log you posted is hard to read because you lost newlines and some words are broken. Could you please format it properly?

Comment: Which exact parameters do you pass to ota_from_target_files.py? On which AOSP version is based your build? Or at least specify the version of Project-Fluid. ota_from_target_files.py gets changes every Android version. I have experience with the version from AOSP 10.